# How to match nested values in RethinkDB?

Tags: python-2.7, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python

I use Python client driver and the structure of my documents is :

```
{"key1": ["value1"], "key2": ["value2"], ..., "key7": ["value7"]}
```

let say "value7" is "In every time in every place, deeds of men remain the same"

I'd like to retrieve all documents that contain "deed" for key7.

I tried

```
r.db('db')
 .table('table')
 .filter(lambda row: row['key7'].match('^deed'))
 .run(conn)
```

but it doesn't work... I have the follwing message :

> rethinkdb.errors.ReqlQueryLogicError: Expected type STRING but found
>   ARRAY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution :

```
r.db('db')
 .table('table')
 .filter(lambda row: row['key7'].nth(0).match('^deed'))
 .run(conn)
```